# Adding or replacing the current date to the end of a file or folder name

Tags: file, date, applescript, directory, rename

Would love some help with an applescript that will rename the current selected file or folder by adding the current date (YYYY-MM-DD) at the end of the filename before the file extension, or if a date exists in the file name then updating it to the current date.

Eg:

Image 1.jpeg

to

Image 1 2019-04-02.jpeg

I have found some useful bits of code already from [Applescript New Folder Named By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871276/applescript-new-folder-named-by-date)
and https://gist.github.com/mnot/221399

I have modified them to create a mostly working piece of applescript.
The only part that I cant figure out is how to check if a date already exists in a file name and then how to replace it. Currently my applescript will just keep adding the date every time it is run.

Not sure if this will make any difference but it would be safe to assume that no file would end in XXXX-XX-XX (X = any digit).

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set the source_folder to (folder of the front window) as text
    on error -- no open folder windows
        display dialog "Please select a file to apply date to" buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
    set these_items to the selection
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
    set this_item to (item i of these_items) as alias
    set this_info to info for this_item
    set {file_name, file_ext} to splitExtension from the name of this_info
    set x to my the_perfect_datestring()
    set new_name to file_name & " " & x & "" & file_ext
    -- check to see if it's already there
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set name of this_item to new_name
        on error -- no open folder windows
            display dialog "Error - File may already exist" buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
        end try
    end tell
end repeat


on the_perfect_datestring()
    try
        set cd to (the current date)
        set the_year to year of (cd) as number
        set the_month to month of (cd) as number
        set the_day to day of (cd) as number
        if the_month < 10 then set the_month to "0" & the_month
        if the_day < 10 then set the_day to "0" & the_day
        return ((the_year & "-" & the_month & "-" & the_day) as text)
    on error
        return "-ERROR"
    end try
end the_perfect_datestring


to splitExtension from file_name
    set dot to "."
    tell AppleScript
        set oT to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to dot
        if (count text items of file_name) > 1 then
            set out_name to (text items 1 through -2 of file_name) as string
            set ext to last text item of file_name
        else
            set out_name to file_name
            set ext to ""
        end if
        set text item delimiters to oT
        if ext is not "" then set ext to dot & ext
        return {out_name, ext}
    end tell
end splitExtension
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another approach which creates the time stamp with the shell and checks if the date exists with `NSRegularExpression` of the `Foundation` framework

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

-- the pattern searches for 4 digits, one hyphen, 2 digits, one hyphen, 2 digits at the end of the string
property datePattern : "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"

tell application "Finder"
    try
        set the sourceFolder to (folder of the front window) as text
    on error -- no open folder windows
        display dialog "Please select a file to apply date to" buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
    set theseItems to the selection
end tell

repeat with anItem in theseItems
    -- extract file name and file extension
    set {name:Nm, name extension:fileExtension} to anItem
    -- strip the file extension
    set baseName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in Nm) - 1) of Nm
    -- create the timestamp in format YYYY-MM-DD
    set currentDate to do shell script "/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d"
    if fileNameHasDate(baseName) then
        -- replace the last 11 characters with the new timestamp
        set newName to text 1 thru -11 of baseName & currentDate
    else
        -- append the timestamp to the file name
        set newName to baseName & space & currentDate
    end if
    -- add the file extension if there was one
    if fileExtension is not "" then set newName to newName & "." & fileExtension
    -- rename the file
    tell application "Finder" to set name of contents of anItem to newName
end repeat

-- checks if the date string exists in the filename. Returns boolean true or false
on fileNameHasDate(fileName)
    set regex to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:datePattern options:0 |error|:(missing value)
    set numberOfMatches to regex's numberOfMatchesInString:fileName options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:(count fileName)}
    return (numberOfMatches as integer) is 1
end fileNameHasDate
```

Side-note: As `AppleScriptObjC` is involved *lowerCamelCased* variable names are used

Comment: Nice work, everything is as expected! Thank you so much for your help. I think I'd better do some homework around the 'foundation' framework to further understand this.